# how to make a message after updating a value without canceling the update

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, beforeupdate

I have to check that the update of a note is not inferior to 10% with a trigger. if it is greater than 10% I have to adjust it to 10% and write an error message , and if the new note is under 0 i have to set it to 0

when i try raise_application error, the update is just cancel.
and my order option DBMS does not work the update is done with the good value but without message

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER C3_update
BEFORE UPDATE OF note on Inscription
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.note < OLD.note*0.9)
begin
    if(:NEW.note > 0) then
    :NEW.note := :OLD.note*0.9;
    dbms_output.enable;
    dbms_output.put_line ('la note ne peut descendre de plus de 10%');
    --or
    --RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20111,'the note can not be less than 10%');
    end if;

    if(:NEW.note < 0) then 
    :NEW.note := 0;
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011,'the note can not be under 0');
    end if;
  end;
  /
```

i would like to set the note and print message error rigth now i just cancel the update or i update the note in the good way but the message do not print

Comment: When you say *"write an error message"* what do you mean by that? Do you want to log a message in (say) a table? Communicate something to the user? Do you mean **error** - which implies failure or rollback - or do you really mean **warning**, which gives a message but allows the transaction to complete? I guess the latter, but it would help if you explained your whole requirement more clearly.

Comment: yes a need to do a warning so give a message and allows the transaction

Comment: Then a trigger is the wrong approach. It happens in the background. You need client-side code to give warnings to the client. Also, RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR throws an **error** (the clue is in the name), which causes the transaction to rollback.

Comment: i have to do it with a trigger its a part of the challenge

Comment: We tend to assume questions here are real life programming problems, and propose the sort of solutions we would use in our jobs. So you need to **edit your question** to make it clear that this is a game (or homework). Include the terms and limitations imposed by this "challenge". Such as how you run the updates (SQL\*Plus?).

Comment: i'm sorry its my first time here so yes its a game and i have to do it with a trigger and on sqlplus

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, this is a wrong approach. Business rule shouldn't be enforced by a database trigger. If I were you, I'd put it into a front-end application (the same place where a new note value is being entered).

Doing so, you'd even be able to notify user what's happening and let them decide whether they want to accept a new value (which you'd suggest, based on those conditions), or not (and, possibly, enter a new, valid value).

As you've noticed, `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` doesn't work. It would, if tool you use to update the note value is capable of displaying it. (By the way, did you `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`?) If you're using, for example, Oracle Forms, then you'd see *nothing*.

`RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`, when called, *ends the subprogram and returns a user-defined error number and message*. However, it also nullifies the update you make. Even if you set the trigger to be an autonomous transaction, it won't work. For example:

```
SQL> drop table inscription;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table inscription (note number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into inscription (note) values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> create or replace trigger c3_update
  2    before update of note on inscription
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.note < old.note * 0.9)
  5  declare
  6    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  7    l_note inscription.note%type;
  8    l_info varchar2(100);
  9  begin
 10    if :new.note > 0 then
 11       :new.note := :old.note * 0.9;
 12       l_info := 'the note can not be less than 10%';
 13    elsif :new.note < 0 then
 14       :new.note := 0;
 15       l_info := 'the note can not be under 0';
 16    end if;
 17    -- Let's hope that COMMIT will save the updated value
 18    select note into l_note from inscription;
 19    dbms_output.put_line('Note before commit = ' || l_note);
 20    commit;
 21    select note into l_note from inscription;
 22    dbms_output.put_line('Note after commit = ' || l_note);
 23
 24    -- Raise the "error", hoping that it'll just display a message,
 25    -- but updated value will remain "as is"
 26    raise_application_error(-20001, l_info);
 27  end;
 28  /

Trigger created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> update inscription set note = -1;
Note before commit = 2
Note after commit = 2
update inscription set note = -1
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: the note can not be under 0
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.C3_UPDATE", line 22
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.C3_UPDATE'


SQL> select * from inscription;

      NOTE
----------
         2
```

See? Instead of `0`, note keeps its original value (`2`). It never even got value 0 because trigger didn't end successfully. How to check that? By commenting the `RAISE` command:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger c3_update
  2    before update of note on inscription
  3    for each row
  4    when (new.note < old.note * 0.9)
  5  declare
  6    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  7    l_note inscription.note%type;
  8    l_info varchar2(100);
  9  begin
 10    if :new.note > 0 then
 11       :new.note := :old.note * 0.9;
 12       l_info := 'the note can not be less than 10%';
 13    elsif :new.note < 0 then
 14       :new.note := 0;
 15       l_info := 'the note can not be under 0';
 16    end if;
 17    -- Let's hope that COMMIT will save the updated value
 18    select note into l_note from inscription;
 19    dbms_output.put_line('Note before commit = ' || l_note);
 20    commit;
 21    select note into l_note from inscription;
 22    dbms_output.put_line('Note after commit = ' || l_note);
 23
 24    -- Raise the "error", hoping that it'll just display a message,
 25    -- but updated value will remain "as is"
 26    --raise_application_error(-20001, l_info);
 27  end;
 28  /

Trigger created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> update inscription set note = -1;
Note before commit = 2
Note after commit = 2

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from inscription;

      NOTE
----------
         0
```

It *does* the job, but - the message can't be displayed (I already told you why).

If you meant to include `UPDATE inscription set note = its_new_value` into the trigger itself, don't - you'll get a deadlock as the initial update fires a trigger which performs update which calls a trigger which performs update etc.

Therefore, as far as I can tell, you can't do what you want, not with a trigger.